# remove empty keys powershell

Tags: powershell, hash, key

I'm trying to remove all keys that are empty from my hash using this code:

```
foreach ($key in $OUHash.Keys){
    if ($($OUHash.Item($key)) -eq $NULL) {
        $OUHash.Remove($key)
    }
}
```

This removes one empty key, but not all, it also gives me this error message:

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
At C:\AD\Shadow group Sync.ps1:31 char:10
+ foreach ($key in $Hash.Keys){
+          ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException
```

Answer (score 7):

While the solution provided by Martin does successfully filter out items with empty values, it returns an Object instead of Hashtable (or OrderedDictionary if you used `[ordered]` attribute).

It's though possible to remove the unnecessary items from the hashtable itself by changing the condition of **Where-Object** (alias `?`) to return only the items with empty values and piping the resulting Object (hence the parentheses) into **ForEach-Object** function (alias `%`):

```
($OuHash.GetEnumerator() | ? { -not $_.Value }) | % { $OuHash.Remove($_.Name) }
```

Another yet very similar approach is to get all hashtable keys in an array Object and pipe it to **ForEach-Object**:

```
@($OuHash.keys) | % { 
    if (-not $OuHash[$_]) { $OuHash.Remove($_) } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect. Still able to do | ConvertTo-Json after.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `GetEnumerator()` method to filter the entries using  [Where-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423) (alias `?`):

```
$OuHash.GetEnumerator() | ? Value
```